# Connected Component Algorithm Not Differentiating Between Objects

Tags: c++, algorithm, computer-vision, computer-science

I am trying to write a program that takes a binary image and uses the sequential labeling algorithm to label each object and then color them a shade a gray different from each other.

I believe my program is differentiating alright, but it does not color them different colors.  I am using the union/find algorithm to combine labels.

Any help would be great:

```
#include "Image.h"
#include "Image.cpp"
#include "Pgm.cpp"
#include "DisjSets.h"
#include "DisjSets.cpp"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char **argv){
  if(argc != 3){
    std::cout << "Use as p2 <input image> <output image name>" << std::endl;
    return 0;
  }

  Image *im;
  im = new Image;

  if(readImage(im, argv[1]) != 0){
    cout << "File " << argv[1] << " could not be opened." << endl;
    return 0;
  }

  int labels[im->getNRows()][im->getNCols()];
  int linked[im->getNRows()];

  for(int x = 0; x < im->getNRows(); x++){
    for(int y = 0; y < im->getNCols(); y++){
      labels[x][y] = 0; //fill the labels array
      linked[x] = 0;
    }
  }

  int current_label = 1;

  DisjSets *disj;
  disj = new DisjSets(im->getNRows());

  int rows = im->getNRows();
  int cols = im->getNCols();

  for(int r = 0; r < rows; r++)
    for(int c = 0; c < cols; c++){
      if(r-1<0 || c-1<0){
        r++;
        c++;
        continue;
      }
      if(im->getPixel(r,c) == 1){
        if(im->getPixel(r-1, c) == 0 && im->getPixel(r, c-1) == 0) {
          if(labels[r][c] == 0 && labels[r-1][c] == 0 && labels[r][c-1] == 0){
          linked[current_label] = current_label;
          labels[r][c] = current_label;
          current_label += 1;
        }
        }else{
        if((im->getPixel(r-1, c) == 1) && im->getPixel(r, c-1) == 0){
          labels[r][c] = labels[r-1][c];
        }
        else if((im->getPixel(r-1, c) == 0) && im->getPixel(r, c-1) == 1){
          labels[r][c] = labels[r][c-1];
        }
        else if((im->getPixel(r-1, c) == 1) && im->getPixel(r, c-1) == 1){
          if(labels[r-1][c] == labels[r][c-1] && labels[r-1][c] != 0 && labels[r][c-1] != 0){
            labels[r][c] = labels[r-1][c];
          } else {
              if(labels[r][c-1] < labels[r-1][c] && labels[r-1][c] != 0 && labels[r][c-1] != 0){
                labels[r][c] = labels[r][c-1];
                linked[labels[r][c]] = disj->unionSets(linked[labels[r][c]], labels[r-1][c]);
            } else if(labels[r][c-1] > labels[r-1][c] && labels[r-1][c] != 0 && labels[r][c-1] != 0){
              labels[r][c] = labels[r-1][c];
              linked[labels[r][c]] = disj->unionSets(linked[labels[r][c]], labels[r][c-1]);
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}


      for(int r = 0; r < im->getNRows(); r++){
        for(int c = 0; c < im->getNCols(); c++){
          if(labels[r][c] != labels[r+1][c+1] && labels[r][c] != labels[r+1][c] && labels[r][c+1])
            cout << labels[r][c] << " ";
          if(im->getPixel(r,c) == 1){
            labels[r][c] = disj->find(linked[labels[r][c]]);
            if(labels[r][c] < 30){
              im->setPixel(r,c,1);
            } else if(labels[r][c] > 30)
              im->setPixel(r,c,2);
          }

        }
      }



  if(writeImage(im, argv[2]) != 0){
    cout << "Cannot write to file: " << argv[2] << endl;
    return 0;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

EDIT: Ok so it turns out, if I print my labels array, all of my labels are 0.  Can someone explain why this is happening?

EDIT2: I fixed it so that I fill the labels array, but I am not sure how to go about doing the pixel color changing. Also updated the code

Comment: Please ask more specific question, is there a specific issue with code?

Comment: No, there are no coding errors.  It just when I am setting the pixels to different colors, both of the objects are showing up as the same color.  I am not sure if it is a problem with the labeling algorithm itself or the way I am using the disjoint sets